# Export dataframe into different sheets in an Excel without deleting the existing ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 and I want to export it to an Excel which already has some sheets.

I tried using:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'test1', index = False)
writer.save()
```

This code deletes the existing sheets, and exports df1 into sheet named test1.

Comment: Have you tried loading the existing excel file as a dataframe and then appending the new data to it before finally exporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'test1', index = False)
writer.save()
```

Just gotta append

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html there is an append mode for ExcelWriter